# Error with scroll in the flatlist wth gesture detector

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, flatlist

I'm develop the flatlist with gesture detector to enable the pinch to zoom, double tap, and pan in the image, but at the moment when the pass to the next image is very difficult I have to move the finger to what works

```
  const contextValues = useMemo(
    () => ({
      onBegin: () => {
        setIsScrollEnabled(false);
      },
      onEnd: () => {
        setIsScrollEnabled(true);
      },
      simultaneousPanGestureRef: listRef.current,
    }),
    [],
  );
 <ZoomListContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
        <GestureDetector gesture={listRef.current}>
          <View style={styles.containerPreview}>
            <PreviewHeader />
            <Carousel
              data={imagesObj}
              getItemLayout={(_, index) => ({
                length: width,
                offset: width * index,
                index,
              })}
              initialNumToRender={currentIndex}
              initialScrollIndex={currentIndex}
              key={landscape ? 'landscape' : 'portrait'}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              scrollEnabled={isScrollEnabled}
              scrollEventThrottle={8}
              showIndicators={false}
              snapToInterval={width}
              viewabilityConfig={{
                itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50,
                waitForInteraction: true,
              }}
              onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
            />
          </View>
        </GestureDetector>
      </ZoomListContext.Provider>
```

```
this is the renderItem



 <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
        <Animated.View style={style} onLayout={memoizedOnLayout}>
          <Thumbnail
            //resizeMode={landscape ? 'contain' : null}
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={{ uri: preview }}
            style={styles.imagePreview}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </GestureDetector>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
```

and addition in the render item I agree the next code for connecting the gesture detector of the flatlist and the gesture detector of the item

```
 if (zoomContext?.simultaneousPanGestureRef) {
    pan.simultaneousWithExternalGesture(zoomContext?.simultaneousPanGestureRef);
  }
```

is there any way to make this work correctly?